# SOAP services call form C# with xml as input

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I wanted to communicate with remotely hosted web services. These are the SOAP services. I have to pass the xml as an input.

I have following piece of code written in PHP works good.

```
$options = array(
    'location' => 'http://192.168.1.200/abcServices',
    'uri' => 'http://192.168.1.200/abcServices'
);

$client = new SoapClient(null, $options);
$soapRequest = "<A><b xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">0</b><c><d xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">2</d></c></A>";
$response = $client->__doRequest($soapRequest, 'http://192.168.1.200/abcServices', '', '1.1');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

But,  I need to write a ASP.NET application to call the services. Can anyone give the equivalent C# code of above php code?

Comment: Why not simply use WCF or Web API (both part of the .NET framework)?  Is there a driving reason you need to do this by hand?

Comment: @tim Yes, Actually the web services are already there. I am not caring with the server side,  I just have to make a client to consume the services.

Comment: Since it's a SOAP service, you could still use WCF to create the client for you - just use "Add Service Reference".  This will generate the proxy and you can use that in your code to send the requests.

Comment: @tim, while trying to add service, I got following responses `code`The document at the url http://192.168.1.200/iWsService was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Root element is missing.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Root element is missing.'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (0, 0).'.
  - Root element is missing.`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post work for me and try to embedded the same in your end. Any difficulties then please do let me know.

[.NET Soap request to Web service - Action not happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468708/net-soap-request-to-web-service-action-not-happening)